# Could not build Objective-C module 'JSQMessagesViewController'

Tags: objective-c, xcode, swift, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

I have two projects which both use JSQMessagesViewController, however in one of them I am getting the error: "Could not build Objective-C module 'JSQMessagesViewController'", whereas the other one works fine...There is virtually no difference between the two projects, how do I get JSQMessagesViewController to work because it is essential to my application. Thanks.

Comment: did you follow these instructions ? https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html

Comment: I did not follow those...I just used cocoa pods to install the required dependencies. All other frameworks work except for this specific one.

Comment: you want to use objective-c module in swift right ?

Comment: Yes I do but I thought cocoapods would handle that all in the backend, I mean it worked with other frameworks like firebase and crashlytics...

Answer (score 45, accepted):

I fixed the problem by going through the following steps:

- Clean the project, including the build cache (Command-Option-Shift-K)
- Removing the pod.lock file and the pods.xcodeproj files
- And then closing Xcode and running pod update again
- Then building again.

Comment: Side Note: Running Xcode 7.3.1 - Just cleaning the project and including the build cache solved the problem for me!

Comment: Solved my problem as well. Thank you!

Comment: When you say 'remove the pods.xcodeproj files' . Do you mean just remove the pods.xcodeproj file ? or remove it and all the other files located in the same directory ?

Comment: @AziCode Hopefully you already figured it out but I meant just the pods.xcodeproj file

Comment: @AhadSheriff I am getting same problem in Xcode 8 and my code is written in Swift 2.3 I tried according to your answer , I could not get success.may you guide me little bit.

Comment: This solution does not work for me also. I'm integrating MSGraphSDK_NXOAuth2Adapter.

Comment: You sir is a genious!

Comment: deleting .lock and .xcodeproj file will not harm to an existing project?

Comment: It would appear that my issue was that I had upgraded Cocoapods to 1.8.0.beta.1 because, you know...shiny new. Going back to 1.7.5 got me back up and running with no errors.

Answer (score -1):

try to install the latest version of JSQMessagesViewController which is on develop right now through 
(pod 'JSQMessagesViewController', :git => 'https://github.com/jessesquires/JSQMessagesViewController.git', :branch => 'develop')
it worked for me ..