# Could not build Objective-C module 'XMPPFramework'

Tags: ios, swift, xmppframework

I am trying to develop the chat application in IOS swift using XMPP. For this, i installed XMPPFramework through Pod install.Below is my Podfile

> #
>
> platform :ios, '9.0'
>
> use_frameworks!
>
> target 'XMPP-Messanger-IOS' do
>
> pod 'XMPPFramework', :podspec =>
>   'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/andrey-justo-movile/XMPPFramework/3.7.2/XMPPFramework.podspec.json'
>
> pod “xmpp-messenger-ios”
>
> end
>
> #

When I try to import XMPPFramework in project I am getting 'Could not build Objective-C module 'XMPPFramework' error.Can anyone please help me to fix this issue

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38076495/could-not-build-objective-c-module-jsqmessagesviewcontroller

Comment: I created bridging header file and imported XMPP Objective C header files and followed all below steps
1.Under Build Settings, in Packaging, make sure the Defines Module setting for that framework target is set to “Yes”.
2.Clean the project, including the build cache (Command-Option-Shift-K)
3.Removing the pod.lock file and the pods.xcodeproj files 
4.And then closing Xcode and running pod update again. Then building again. Then also i am getting same error .