# Getting an error in QuadratTouch when I do Pod Install? -Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, realm, foursquare

I am creating a coffee shop app where when I did pod install, it got installed and when I open the .xcworkspace I get an error to QuadraTouch and also Realm saying "Could Not build Object-C module 'QuadratTouch'? Does anyone know what is going on?

> Here is my pod file

```
 platform :ios, '10.2'

  use_frameworks!

 target 'CoffeeShop' do


 pod 'QuadratTouch', '>= 1.0'
 pod 'RealmSwift'

  end
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26834293/swift-could-not-build-objective-c-module-alamofire

Comment: see this also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38076495/could-not-build-objective-c-module-jsqmessagesviewcontroller

Comment: I tried it. no luck whatsoever.

Comment: try this `pod 'QuadratTouch', '~> 1.0'` and add command `pod install`

Comment: Nope! Thats the error is shows in my updated question.

Comment: check once your `QuadratTouch` is adoptable for swift3 or not

Comment: how can I check it? https://github.com/Constantine-Fry/das-quadrat

Comment: try with `pod 'QuadratTouch', '~> 1.1.3`, you can get the pod spec https://github.com/Constantine-Fry/das-quadrat/blob/master/QuadratTouch.podspec

Comment: check updated question. I am getting this error in terminal: "Invalid `Podfile` file: syntax error, unexpected tCONSTANT, expecting keyword_end
pod 'RealmSwift'"

Comment: are you missed the `'` end of  `pod 'QuadratTouch', '~> 1.1.3'`, update and run once

Comment: Now getting that error in updated question. I did pod repo update it says: "CocoaPods was not able to update the `master` repo. If this is an unexpected issue and persists you can inspect it running `pod repo update --verbose`"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137023/discussion-between-d-w-and-anbu-karthik).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess master branch of QuadratTouch is not fully swift 3 compatible.

You have to use 'fry-swift30' branch. Update your podfile like below.

```
pod 'QuadratTouch', :git => 'https://github.com/Constantine-Fry/das-quadrat', :branch => 'fry-swift30'
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using Swift 3 and `QuadratTouch` is not fully swift 3 compatible.

Update your podfile like below removing version specification.

```
 pod 'QuadratTouch'
```

Run `pod repo update` command and the `pod install --verbose`

Comment: Now it gives: "The file “RealmSwift.xcconfig” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file"

Comment: Then it might be problem while installing your pods. Please try to install it again and clean and build.